# React native - enable notification on locked screen

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

I need to display notification on top of phone even when screen is locked, in react-native for android. I am using package "react-native-firebase".

below is the code that I tried:

```
const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
  'goofy',  
  'goofy the goofy',
  firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max
)   
.setDescription('ideally should work')
.enableLights(true)
.enableVibration(true)
.setLockScreenVisibility(firebase.notifications.Android.Visibility.Public);
```

Still I am getting below configuration in settings:

[image]

Am I missing something? Ideally these buttons should be enabled.

Comment: I know it's old, but I'm getting the same problem. Did you get any solution?